# How to get caller element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a table with id "tbl" and it has 2 rows and 3 cols. Each cell (td) has an explicitly defined id. Also, the table has an `onclick` event that calls a function `foo()`. The `onclick()` would be generated whenever any cell is clicked.
The table tag is:

```
< table id="tbl" width="80%" height="20%" onclick="javascript: foo()" >
```

I also tried `javascript:foo(this)`

I want to find out the id of the table cell that was clicked.

I have tried the following JavaScript:

```
function foo(e)
{
    var sender = (e && e.target) || (window.event && window.event.srcElement);
    alert("Sender" + sender.id);
}
```

This works great in Google Chrome and IE, but not in Firefox. In Firefox, sender is undefined.
How to get the caller cell in Firefox?

Comment: I won't put it as an answer (a little too asinine maybe?), but why aren't you using jQuery where all the differences in browsers are handled for you? Also, it makes assigning onClick handlers a little more straightforward, in some ways...

Comment: @drachenstern: you had to go there...

Comment: @drachenstern: I think force-feeding jQuery is going a bit too far.  All the popular frameworks handle browser differences. jQuery is my favourite too, but I think "why aren't you using a framework?" is a  more unbiased question to ask.

Comment: @drachenstern: Shouldn't I be good with Javascript before trying JQuery ?

Comment: @Andy E's head ~ +1 very good point, I'll amend my question in the future. Thanks for the enlightenment.

Comment: @wacky_coder ~ not for something like this, because there's a difference between learning how to encompass all browser quirks and learning how to write code to do things in javascript. I use the framework to handle the quirks and the nitty gritty, and I write the functional parts myself. Same as I do with C#. I don't try and figure how to read the filesystem, I use the .NET framework to do that for me, and I write code to do the functional part. I can extend that analogy to many things, for instance Lists. But you're correct, you should know WHY it works like it does, as your code shows. +1

Comment: @wacky_coder ~ I want to point this out, just to be clear: I'm not against roll your own, especially for something simple like this, because I started writing JS long before I learnt jQuery, but I seemed to always get caught up in the tedium of remembering to check everything for each browser. If you don't goto a framework, at least write your own pseudoframework, so you don't have to handle cross-browser differences in every function. That's the biggest benefit to a framework. Yes there's plugins, so those are fun, but those aren't the reason I switched to framework js code...

Comment: @drachenstern : Even I use the .NET framework for most of the work. It handles all the pain I would have been required to take in but sometimes, one has to write code without using the facilities provided by the framework. That's when I have to dive in!

Comment: @wacky_coder ~ indeed! but hopefully it masks most of the painful bits for you ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, remove `javascript:` from the `onclick` attribute.  You're confusing this with javascript in the `href` attribute of a link.  In Javascript code, `javascript:` would create a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/label) named "javascript".

Other than that, `foo(event)` should work correctly with your final JavaScript code sample.  The reason it doesn't work in Firefox but does in Chrome and IE is; they both support the global event object, `window.event` (which is evaluated when your `e.target` yields `undefined`, because `this` is an element which will not have a `target` property).  Firefox doesn't support the global `event` object.

Further reading:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:event